# AWS lambda Dockerfile ImportModuleError

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I have created a Dockerfile that looks like this.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.4.0

RUN pip install "poetry==$POETRY_VERSION"

WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create true && poetry install --only main --no-interaction --no-ansi

COPY scraper_backend ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/scraper_backend
COPY app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/


CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

With my app.py looking like this.

```
from scraper_backend.jobs import main

def handler(event, context):
    main()
```

I build my docker file with `docker build -t etl_pipeline .`
I run my docker file with `docker run -p 9000:8080 etl_pipeline` and I'm testing it by executing the following command in my terminal `curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{}'` But I keep getting this error

```
{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'polars'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "requestId": "277e7f20-ae8d-4d12-b3b1-148e1106eda1", "stackTrace": []}
```

I'm using poetry and polars is in my pyproject.toml, and I'm installing all my packages in my Dockerfile. Also I don't understand why it cannot import the module 'app' I guess this refers to my app.py. If someone can shed some light on my problem I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The error message from `no module named polars` came from that my virtual environment failed. So I changed this line

```
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create true && poetry install --only main --no-interaction --no-ansi
to 
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false
RUN poetry install --only main --no-interaction --no-ansi
```

Also instead of copying my scraper_backend folder and my app.py i copied my everything with
`COPY . ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/`

I do highely recommend for people who are encoutering problems with their docker file to run your docker image with the `-it` flag so you can go in the terminal from Docker Desktop and start debugging your problem, this was very helpfull in my case.